# table-responsive only show scroll bar when needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When wrapping a table in  a horizontal scrollbar is shown even if it isn't required (i.e. on desktop).

I tried removing table-responsive but then mobile can't scroll at all.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="w-100 text-center product-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><i class="fal fa-microchip"></i><br>CPU</th>
                       ...
                        <th></th> {# empty column for action button #}
                    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The horizontal scroll bar showing in chrome on a 4k monitor really doesn't make a lot of sense, is there a way to make it only show the scroll bar when it's required?

Comment: try remove `w-100` class from table

Comment: Well. that definitely got rid of the scroll bar but it made the table as small as possible which also looks a little crazy on a desktop browser.